# Sencha ExtJS Append HTML Control To Application

Tags: javascript, extjs

So I am new to both Sencha and Javascript. I have been stuck on this for the last couple hours or so. I trying to append a standard HTML5 control to a Sencha ExtJS panel for use within the application. This is the control:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" />
```

I found a couple forums that kinda explain how to do it but I am doing something wrong here is what the forums explain:

From the Forums:

> Ext.DomHelper.append('parent-div', {tag: 'div', cls: 'new-div-cls', id: 'new-div-id'});
>
> myEl = new Ext.Element(document.createElement('div'));
>
> Ext.Get('par-div').appendChild(myEl);

Here is what I have tried:

```
Ext.onReady(function () 
    {           
        Ext.DomHelper.append('parent-div', {tag: 'div', cls: 'new-div-cls', id: 'new-div-id'});

        var c = Ext.Get('par-div');


        //var myEl = new Ext.Element(document.createElement('div'));
        //Ext.Get('par-div').appendChild(myEl.dom);

        //var mi = document.createElement("input");
        //mi.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        //mi.setAttribute('value', 'default');

        //var myEl = new Ext.Element(mi);

        //Ext.Get('par-div').appendChild(myEl);

        var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items:  [myEl]
        });
    });
```

The problem is I have no idea where to add this and how to display it.

Overall I am just trying to take an HTML 5 input control and add it to my Sencha app.

Thanks,

Josh

Update:

cpastore84, Thank you for the reply. So I have a bit of code that pretty much does what you have and works the issue now is that it is putting the input field behind the panel I am trying to place it in:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Hello',
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            html: '<p>World!</p>',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners:
            {
                render: function( sender, eOpts )
                {
                    var form = document.createElement('form');

                    var input = document.createElement('input');
                    input.name = 'parentNode';
                    input.type = 'file';

                    form.appendChild(input);

                    //var myEl = new Ext.Element(form);

                    var h = document.getElementById(sender.id);

                    h.appendChild(form);


                    alert(h);
                }
            }
        });
```

You can see the input box appear before the panel is rendered on top. I hope  this is something simple to fix. Any idea's?

Update 2:

I have also tried grabbing the innerHTML from the element and replacing a dummy

with the input. It does technically work but loses all of the original format when you set the innerHTML to the newly modified version. Any idea why it would do that when only changing one line?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xzLht4d/1/) showing an example.
The script itself is simple. Just pass the parent container's id to the append method:

```
Ext.DomHelper.append('parent-div', {tag:'input', type:'file', id:'files', name:'file'});
```

You can add the script to the head of your html file like so:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.DomHelper.append('parent-div', {tag:'input', type:'file', id:'files', name:'file'}); 
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent-div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

then it will run after the page is loaded.

### Update

It's easier to add the field to the panel using the panel's items array rather than try to manipulate the component's DOM directly. Here is an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xzLht4d/2/) showing the relevant items array:

```
items : [
    {
        xtype: 'filefield',
        name: 'file'
    }
]
```

### Update 2

You can render any markup by passing a DomSpec to the component's autoEl config:

```
{
  xtype : 'component',
  autoEl: {
    tag : 'input',
    type: 'file'
  }
}
```

See the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xzLht4d/3/).

Comment: cpastore84, Please see my update at the top. I did not know how to directly reply. Thanks

Comment: @JoshC I updated my answer. If you're trying to place the field inside a component use the items array or call the component's add method.

Comment: cpastore84 It was my first instinct to use the filefield but then after further reading I discovered that the filefield will not read the file contents locally and that it must make a round trip ride to the server so that is why I switched over to the input file with HTML5 which allows you to read the contents very quickly client side. I have attempted to add my DOM object using the .add keyword but receive an error. Is there a way for me to add my newly created DOM object to the component?

Comment: cpastore84, I left another update for you. I hope I am getting closer. Thanks. @cpastore84

Comment: @JoshC I think the autoEl config is what you're after then!

Comment: cpastore84, so I know this is going to sound incredible but I think I ended up having a case of classic over thinking. I was doing all this coding to try to insert this control then it donned on me the panel control contains a config called 'HTML'. Right so I set that to the html for my input and so far it showed up. Yeah. Now just got to work the functionality. @cpastore84

Comment: cpastore84. You seem to be very familiar with the Sencha stuff and I am brand new at both Sencha and JS. I don't know how to send private messages on here but would you mind if other questions come up if I messaged you if that is even possible? @cpastore84

Comment: @JoshC you can render the HTML directly, or use the autoEl config which means that `component.getEl()` will return you the input element itself (may help when you need to read the contents). There are no PMs at SO, but just tag your questions with ExtJS so anyone can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys thanks for everyone's support. I was able to figure out how to do this and wanted to post the end all code for everyone. I could not have done it without everyone's help though. I hope this will be of assistance to someone else as well.

```
var myPanal = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Hello',
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: 
            [
                {xtype: 'datefield',fieldLabel: 'Start date'}, 
                {xtype: 'panel', id: 'pnlTest', html: '<input type="file" id="files" width="500" name="file" />'},
                {xtype: 'button', width:75, height: 25, text: 'Read', margin: '5 0 0 5', handler:function()
                { 
                    var inputFiles = document.getElementById('files');

                    var file = inputFiles.files[0];
                    var start = 0;
                    var stop = file.size - 1;

                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onloadend = function(evt) 
                    {
                      if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) 
                      { 
                        alert(evt.target.result);
                      }
                    };

                    var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
                    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
                }}
            ]
        });
```